# Comparing two files and printing similar lines

Tags: python, shell

I've got two text files which both have index lines. I want to compare [file1](https://gist.github.com/bodieskate/5610191) and [file2](https://gist.github.com/bodieskate/5610199) and send the similar lines to a new text file. I've been googling this for awhile now and have been trying grep in various forms but I feel I'm getting in over my head. What I'd like ultimately is to see the 'Mon-######' from file2 that appear in file1 and print the lines from file1 which correspond.

(The files are much larger, I cut them down for brevity's sake)

For even greater clarity:

file1 has entries of the form:

```
Mon-000101  100.27242   9.608597   11.082   10.034
Mon-000102  100.18012   9.520860   12.296   12.223
```

file2 has entries of the form:

```
Mon-000101
Mon-000171
```

So, if the identifier (Mon-000101 for instance) from file2 is listed in file1 I want the entire line that begins with Mon-000101 printed into a separate file. If it isn't listed in file2 it can be discarded.

So if the files were only as large as the above files the newly produced file would have the single entry of

```
Mon-000101  100.27242   9.608597   11.082   10.034
```

because that's the only one common to the both.

Comment: Have you tried using python? Read the second file to create a list of Mon-xxxx that appears, then read the first file, split each line and check if the first field appears in that list

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify: do you mean *identical* lines (in which case `comm` or `diff` should work) or really just "similar"? If the latter, please elaborate on your concept of similarity (edit distance, same letters, same semantics, what?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since from earlier questions you're at least a little familiar with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org), how about:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", sep=r"\s+")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", sep=r"\s+")
merged = df1.merge(df2.rename_axis({"Mon-id": "NAME"}))
merged.to_csv("merged.csv", index=False)
```

---

Some explanation (note that I've modified `file2.csv` so that there are more elements in common) follows.

First, read the data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", sep=r"\s+")
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", sep=r"\s+")
>>> df1.head()
         NAME         RA       DEC  Mean_I1  Mean_I2
0  Mon-000101  100.27242  9.608597   11.082   10.034
1  Mon-000102  100.18012  9.520860   12.296   12.223
2  Mon-000103  100.24811  9.586362    9.429    9.010
3  Mon-000104  100.26741  9.867225   11.811   11.797
4  Mon-000105  100.21005  9.814060   12.087   12.090
>>> df2.head()
       Mon-id
0  Mon-000101
1  Mon-000121
2  Mon-000131
3  Mon-000141
4  Mon-000151
```

Then, we can rename the axis in df2:

```
>>> df2.rename_axis({"Mon-id": "NAME"}).head()
         NAME
0  Mon-000101
1  Mon-000121
2  Mon-000131
3  Mon-000141
4  Mon-000151
```

and after that, `merge` will simply do the right thing:

```
>>> merged = df1.merge(df2.rename_axis({"Mon-id": "NAME"}))
>>> merged
         NAME         RA       DEC  Mean_I1  Mean_I2
0  Mon-000101  100.27242  9.608597   11.082   10.034
1  Mon-000121  100.45421  9.685027   11.805   11.777
2  Mon-000131  100.20533  9.397307 -100.000   11.764
3  Mon-000141  100.26134  9.388555 -100.000   12.571
```

Finally, we can write this out, telling it not to add an index column:

```
>>> merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

producing a file which looks like

```
NAME,RA,DEC,Mean_I1,Mean_I2
Mon-000101,100.27242,9.608597,11.082,10.034
Mon-000121,100.45421,9.685027,11.805,11.777
Mon-000131,100.20533,9.397307,-100.0,11.764
Mon-000141,100.26134,9.388555,-100.0,12.571
```

Comment: THANKS! That did exactly what I needed...and using pandas...bonus. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > duplicated-lines
```

Comment: In this case, it is easy to change the command to get unique lines from each file first...

Comment: I have changed the command to search for duplicates in separate files.

Comment: I don't think "comm" will solve this problem.  Have you tried "join"?  Note that the files only have a single column in common.

Comment: hey, Roman, sorry just checked and looks like you got this answer in before the question was clarified - at the time it was posted this answer was probably helpful.

Comment: @mattbornski, yes, I answered it before it was edited. For the last requirement, `join` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you added the python tag, it seems you want something like this:

```
import csv
f = open('file2')
l = set([l.strip() for l in f.readlines()])
with open('file1', 'rb') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(10024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
    cnt = 0
    for item in reader:
        if cnt >0:
           data = item[0]
           if data in l:
               print item
        cnt = cnt + 1
```

Comment: @carlosdc - I'm trying to run your suggestion and I keep getting `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split.py", line 8, in <module>
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile,dialect)
NameError: name 'dialect' is not defined`                                                                                                                                 Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: I don't do sniff(csvfile,dialect) I do sniff(csvfile.read(10024))

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this (provided the files aren't too large) would be to read in `file1` and store the data as a `dict` where each line is keyed by the index (first column) and the data (remaining columns).  Then read `file2` as a list of keys, which you can then use as a generator to extract matching lines from the data in `file1`.

A quick and dirty solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

DATA_FILE='file1.txt'
KEY_FILE='file2.txt'

# Read a list of keys to search for
keys = []
lineno = 1
for line in open(KEY_FILE):
    if lineno > 1:
        keys.append(line.strip())
    lineno += 1

# Read data 
data = {}
lineno = 1
for line in open(DATA_FILE):
    if lineno > 1:
        fields = line.split()
        data[fields[0]] = fields[1:]
    lineno += 1

    # Extract data using keys

extracted_data = [[k, data[k]] for k in keys if k in data]

for k, v in extracted_data:
    print k, ' '.join(v)
```

There's probably more efficient ways of doing this, but this will do the job, and allow you to put more logic in as required.

Answer (score 0):

As the files may be big, how about this approach; which uses sqlite to handle the file manipulation:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
import os

conn = sqlite3.connect('temp.db')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE master
          (id text, ra text, dec text, mean1 text, mean2 text)''')
conn.commit() # Write changes

with open('master.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    next(reader) # skips header
    for row in reader:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO master VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', row)
        conn.commit()

with open('filter.txt') as f, open('diff.txt','w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(('NAME','RA','DEC','Mean_I1','Mean_I2'))
    for line in f:
         c.execute('SELECT * FROM master WHERE id = ?',(line.strip(),))
         row = c.fetchone()
         if row:
             writer.writerow(row)
conn.close()
os.remove('temp.db')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and `sed` on `bash`. This may not be very performant with very large files.

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' file2.txt) file1.txt
```